# Official term for “at large” or “on the loose”

Tags: word-choice, legalese

When a convict is illegally out of prison – either escaped, or didn't get to the prison after his conviction – what is the right expression to describe this?

I want the term that is used in official documents, like court files, court orders, etc.

Comment: There's the expression _on the lam_, but I don't think that's used in official court documents. _At large_ sounds right to me, but I'm no attorney, so I can't say that emphatically.

Answer (score 9):

In the UK, one is [*unlawfully at large*](http://www.kent.police.uk/about_us/policies/n/n061.html).

> **5. Unlawfully at large from prison**
>   5.1.  A prisoner is unlawfully at large when absent from prison, young offenders institute or remand centre as a result of:
>   *       escaping or absconding from the prison establishment;
>   *            failing to return to the prison establishment after a period of authorised temporary leave, or when the temporary leave has been revoked; or
>   *            failing to return to prison after the revocation of a permanent licence or release, e.g. parole.

I have found a legislative reference: [Prison Act 1952](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Geo6and1Eliz2/15-16/52/section/49)

Comment: That sounds right for North America as well.

Answer (score 4):

[Definition of fugitive](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fugitive):

> a person who has **escaped** from captivity or is **in hiding**:
>
> **fugitives from justice**

According to a legal dictionary, a [fugitive from justice](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Fugitive+from+Justice) is:

> a person **convicted or accused** of a crime who **hides from law enforcement** in the state or **flees** across state lines to avoid arrest or punishment. Under Article IV, Section 2, Governors are required to "deliver up" and return any fugitive from justice to the state where they allegedly committed the crime, a process called extradition.